# How to store arbitrary method pointers in c++11?

Tags: c++, list, c++11, store, pointer-to-member

I need a way to store a list of method pointers, but I don't care about what class they belong to. I had this in mind:

```
struct MethodPointer
{
    void *object;
    void (*method)(void);
};
```

Then I could have have a function which takes an arbitrary method:

```
template <typename T>
void register_method(void(T::*method)(void), T* obj) {
    MethodPointer pointer = {obj, method);

}

void use_method_pointer() {
    ...
    MethodPointer mp = ...

    // call the method
    (mp.object->*method)();

    ...
}
```

This obviously doesn't compile because I can't convert the method pointer into a function pointer in register_method().

The reason I need this is because I have a class which can emit events - and I want arbitrary instances to subscribe to these events as method calls. Is this possible to do?

PS. Conditions apply:
1. I don't want to use Boost
2. I don't want to use a 'Listener' interface, where a subscriber have to subclass an abstract interface class.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: What about making every class inherit from the same base class? It can be empty, it's just that you could get rid of the template.

Comment: What you want already exists in the standard library/ and is called [`function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) Well, it's not quite the same thing but it's what I'd use for a signal/slot mechanism. Note that there are already signal slot libraries for C++. Boost has at least one if I recall.

Comment: Do some casts, all method pointers are the same size.

Comment: @user1095108: That's a terrible, terrible, terrible idea.

Comment: It's not *that* terrible -- it would work, it just wouldn't provide any type-safety guarantees enforced by the compiler, so you'd have to be very careful that your casts were correct, or you'd suffer from run-time errors.  That said, there are definitely better ways to accomplish the same result.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/02/09/70002.aspx It is *that* terrible. Member function pointers *are not* all the same size, not in theory, and not in practice.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes static_assert can guard against that possibility.

Comment: Failure to compile is not an alternative to a working implementation, though.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes and you should be quoting the C++ standard, not a M$ horror novel.

Comment: There's one claim that the standard *does not* put this particular requirement on implementations, and then there is the claim that the standard *does* put this requirement on implementations. Where the burden of quoting lies should be obviou$ here.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes of course it does: [5.2.10] A prvalue of type “pointer to member of X of type T1” can be explicitly converted to a prvalue of a different
type “pointer to member of Y of type T2” if T1 and T2 are both function types or both object types. M$ is violating the standard, as in so many other cases. As for the burden, it lies on you, as you have more rep than I.

Comment: For future reference: the value in my argument$ resides in the portion before  "–  R. Martinho Fernandes", not in the portion that says "111276 reputation" (was that https://yourlogicalfallacyis.com/ad-hominem or https://yourlogicalfallacyis.com/appeal-to-authority?).

Comment: @user1095108 That quote doesn't necessitate that the two pointers are the same size. Just that one can be converted to the other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you are just looking for [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function):

```
using NullaryFunc = std::function<void()>;
```

Registration:

```
template <typename T>
void register_method(void(T::*method)(void), T* obj) {
    NullaryFunc nf = std::bind(method, obj);

    // store nf somewhere  
}
```

Usage:

```
void use_method() {
    ...
    NullaryFunc nf = ...;
    // call the function
    nf();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Does this also appliy if the method pointer I store also takes a parameter?
*EDIT* I just realised it does, as longs as I add std::placeholders::_1 to std::bind. For example std::bind(method, obj, std::placeholders::_1);

Comment: @mrmclovin If you want to store the parameter, yes. If you want to call it later with a parameter, no.

Comment: Hm, I'm starting to think that std::bind wasn't the thing I was looking for. Bind will bind arguments with a function and store it. Or you can use std::placeholders to supply the arguments when the function is invoked. Maybe I'm looking for std::mem_fn. How can I have a list of std::mem_fn which holds instances of different class types?

Comment: @mrmclovin If you have a new question, ask a new question.